# Change password reset mail message in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to translate the message in the mail.

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php`

```
public function toMail()
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line([
            'You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.',
            'Click the button below to reset your password:',
        ])
        ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

What is the best way to change the message? Pretty sure I shouldn't change it in this file..

Answer (score 2):

From [5.3 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords#password-customization):

> You may easily modify the notification class used to send the password reset link to the user. To get started, override the `sendPasswordResetNotification` method on your User model. Within this method, you may send the notification using any notification class you choose. The password reset  $token is the first argument received by the method:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From [Localization in doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization),Language strings are stored in files within the `resources/lang` directory.
create e.g. messages.php

```
<?php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
];
```

and use trans function.

```
echo trans('messages.welcome');
```